# Compute paths through graph vertex

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I have a mesh, in which every vertex has most likely 6 to 8 neighbours. I need to compute like on the picture. For vertex O there are three incoming vertices: A, B and C. And we have these paths: AC, BA, CA. The criterium to choose path - it must be as close to a straight line as possible, so AOC is better then AOB.

I have coordinates $(x, y, z)$ for every vertex. For now i think i need to compute dot products of all pairs: OA, OB, OC and then choose best paths. Is there any possible optimization. E.g. somehow compute only dot products $ OA \cdot OC$ and $ OA \cdot OB$ and deduce right paths from this data?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Using that $\angle BOA + \angle AOB + \angle COB = 2\pi$ you can eliminate one pair per central vertex.

Comment: Worth remembering is that $\beta$ is spelled "beta", not "betta" like the fish.

Comment: @AlexR Betta fish are a kind of fish (aka Siamese Fighting fish)

Comment: @Hayden [such a beautiful typo](http://www.aquariumfish.net/images_01/betta_male_blue_120125a2_w0640.jpg) :)

Comment: I think the word "betta" is a funny link to the word "better", a really good wordplay!